# Assign variable in PowerShell script during TFS build process

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to execute PowerShell script during TFS build process. I added new activity "RunScript" into TFS Build workflow and new arguments. That script works with arguments.

Now I am trying to use returned value in another activity. Actually I would like to assign some global variable with that value in PowerShell script and pass to another process.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Output the value that you want to return with Write-Host then in your Standard Output of the InvokeProcess activity you'll get the value.

Comment: I am not understanding you as well what you want to say. Can you please be more specific? I know that output  arguments can be used whet we want to pass values between activities. But I don't know exactly how can I use them in "RunScript" activity. BTW, in "InvokeProcess" I have problem to point location of "PowerShell" file. I read that for "InvokeProcess" is required to use "ConvertWorkspaceItem" to help point to correct address. But still doesn't work for me.

Comment: In my XAML build I'm using the InvokeProcess activity to run the PowerShell scripts as in http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/part-14-execute-a-powershell-script.aspx

Comment: Thanks, great. I am reading same article. Can you please explain how you call PowerShell script in "InvokeProcess" activity? There is explained that we need to use "ConvertWorkspaceItem" to get correct script path. I am getting error when I tried to set "Workspace" propery. What you used in that property? When I used workspace value which is recommended in article I recieved following error: "compiler error(s) encountered processing expression workspace"!